# Check SQL Server connection status indefinitely

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I wanted to create a connection status to determine SQL connection is offline or not. So I decided to create a thread to while(true). I got no issue on what I am getting:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

and it's taking a toll on the CPU. Is there anyway to do this efficiently?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here... but you can check the `State` property of SqlConnection...[StateProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.state?view=netframework-4.8) and [ConnectionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.connectionstate?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am trying to show a "Status" to user like an indicator, the user will input SQL information such as Database name, password, username, etc and after that the program will determine is it connected shown in label to user

Comment: Make a single connection and use a timer to perform a simple query like `select version()` every 30 seconds. Assuming another part of your app is actually trying to use the db for something useful, don't batter the database with multiple useless connections; you'll cause performance issues elsewhere by upsetting the pooling

Comment: @HowardF Do you want to check if the database server is online or not?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes.

Comment: What does "create a thread to while(true)" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity Is a infinite threaded loop calling the code I shown above

Comment: What does "infinite threaded loop" mean?

Answer (score 0):

you should use 
if (myConn.State != ConnectionState.Open)

and iff it false use:
myConn.Open();